How can I decrypt TLS packets using the output of the SSL key log file in Go?
I am making https requests and logging the keys in using the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable. If I capture the packets using Wireshark, I can decrypt the packets by specifying the path of the key log file. I have another Go program that is using the gopacket and pcap library to capture the packets and I would like to replicate Wireshark's behavior in this program.
My question is how can I use the key log file to decrypt the packet payload in Go? I have been looking at the crypto/tls package to do this but was not able to find this functionality. Any help in finding the right library or help with implementation would be appreciated.

Second hit I get when searching for golang sslkeylogfile decrypt is https://github.com/kiosk404/tls-decrypt, which looks like what you need. Did you already try this?

I have tried to use this library, specifically from decrypt_tls.go, but it seems to only work with TLS 1.2 since it only sets the master key when the label is "CLIENT_RANDOM".
